# Quickfixj setting up sources for development - Could not find artifact org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, visual-studio-code, quickfixj

I can't import successfully the **QuickFIX/J** project into any of my IDEs, I've tried with Eclipse, VS Code and IntelliJ.

Following the [QuickFIX/J](https://github.com/quickfix-j/quickfixj) project instructions, first I build the project with:

```
$ mvn clean package -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -PskipBundlePlugin
```

Everything goes well in the build:

```
[INFO] Building zip: /home/helesto/kdi/github/quickfixj/quickfixj-distribution/target/org.quickfixj-2.2.1-SNAPSHOT-bin.zip
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for QuickFIX/J Parent 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT:
[INFO] 
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Parent .................................. SUCCESS [  4.654 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Code Generator Maven Plugin ............. SUCCESS [ 28.844 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Dictionary Generator .................... SUCCESS [  1.178 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Core engine ............................. SUCCESS [06:51 min]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Message classes for various FIX specs ... SUCCESS [  0.003 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Message classes for FIX 4.0 ............. SUCCESS [  1.028 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Message classes for FIX 4.1 ............. SUCCESS [  0.835 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Message classes for FIX 4.2 ............. SUCCESS [  0.874 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Message classes for FIX 4.3 ............. SUCCESS [  0.839 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Message classes for FIX 4.4 ............. SUCCESS [  1.082 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Message classes for FIX 5.0 ............. SUCCESS [  1.349 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Message classes for FIX 5.0 SP1 ......... SUCCESS [  1.283 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Message classes for FIX 5.0 SP2 ......... SUCCESS [  1.215 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Message classes for FIXT 1.1 ............ SUCCESS [  0.710 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Message classes for all FIX specs ....... SUCCESS [  2.294 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Examples ................................ SUCCESS [  0.004 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Examples - Executor ..................... SUCCESS [  7.030 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Examples - Order Match .................. SUCCESS [  4.830 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Examples - Banzai ....................... SUCCESS [  5.036 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J All runtime modules ..................... SUCCESS [ 18.797 s]
[INFO] QuickFIX/J Distribution ............................ SUCCESS [ 16.725 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  08:31 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-01-15T19:11:18-03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Then I try to import it into the IDEs and something goes wrong with the `quickfixj-codegenerator`.

I've tried some things that I've found on the internet, but nothing solve my problem.

I'll be very happy if someone could help me :)

### My machine

#### Maven

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /kdi/maven
Java version: 11.0.9.1, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.8.0-36-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

#### Java

```
openjdk version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
javac 11.0.9.1
```

#### OS

```
Linux machine 5.8.0-36-generic #40~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 6 10:15:55 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### QuickFIX/J build instructions

At https://www.quickfixj.org/usermanual/2.1.0/installation.html#dependencies I've found:

> IDE support:
> There are Eclipse and Netbeans project definition files in the top-level directory of the checked out directory. When the project is first created, it will not have the generated message classes and compile errors will occur! Best is to compile once on the command line before importing the project into the IDE.

I've searched the project documentation and I didn't find nothing about this issue.

### Eclipse - Error

Version: 2020-12 (4.18.0)

Reports the following error when I import the project:

```
No marketplace entries found to handle maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information.
No marketplace entries found to handle Execution default-descriptor, in /quickfixj-codegenerator/pom.xml in Eclipse.  Please see Help for more information
```

After importing, the /quickfixj-codegenerator/pom.xml says that:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (execution: default-descriptor, phase: process-classes)
```

### VS Code - Error

Version 1.52.1

Error:

```
Could not find artifact org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:jar:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT
```

### IntelliJ - Error

Version Community 2020.3.2

Error:

```
Cannot resolve plugin org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:2.2.1-SNAPSHOT
Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:<unknown>
```

### QuickFIX/J email support - same issue as mine

The same issue was reported on the email of support discussion of Quickfixj:

- https://sourceforge.net/p/quickfixj/mailman/message/36623115/

On the email thread, I didn't find the answer to this problem.

The problem was reported on 2019, March. The only difference for me is that the Quick/FIXJ is now in a newer version.

Quoting the same problem of the email:

> I'm trying to create a development environment for quickfixj on eclipse. I
> cloned the repository, downloaded the sources, and ran the command:
>
> mvn clean package -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -PskipBundlePlugin
>
> just as suggested on the website. This part worked without any errors.
>
> Afterwards, I try to import the projects in eclipse. The projects are
> identified as maven projects and added to the workspace, but when
> compiling, after the import, it shows the error:
> Could not find artifact
> org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT
> Which does not allow quickfixj-core to build, which in turn does not allow
> any other projects to compile, since they all depend on the core project.
>
> I have tried a suggestion I found on the net, to run
> mvn eclipse:eclipse to help build the eclipse projects but by the time it
> reaches the core engine project, it throws the same error:
> [ERROR] Plugin org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT or one
> of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact
> org.quickfixj:quickfixj-codegenerator:jar:2.2.0-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]

Comment: What happens if you run `install` target, so `mvn clean install -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -PskipBundlePlugin` and then refreshing the project in Eclipse? I am using Netbeans for QFJ development but cannot remember if I made any tweaks back then.

Comment: @ChristophJohn thanks a lot! I run with `install` and worked perfectly with IntelliJ. With Eclipse I got the same error and with VS Code things got even worst. I've never used Netbeans, but I'll try it later. I wish I could use VS Code, but IntelliJ will be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully import the project into `IntelliJ` and `Netbeans` using the help of @ChristophJohn.

First, run:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DskipTests -PskipBundlePlugin
```

And then just import it to `IntelliJ` or `Netbeans`.

I wasn't able to import it to Eclipse or VS Code. But, as this worked with `IntelliJ` and `Netbeans`, for me it is enough.

Comment: What happens in Eclipse if you just remove the error from the view via pressing  `Delete` key? And of course disable compilation of the project in Eclipse.

Comment: I've tried this, but didn't work. The other packages can't find some classes, so I receive errors like `ApplExtID cannot be resolved to a variable` on the `/quickfixj-core/src/main/java/quickfix/Message.java`. Probably if I had more abilities in Eclipse, I'll be able to solve this problem. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'll think of something. And will check my Netbeans installation if I did something special there.

Comment: IntelliJ is working perfectly for me. But if you want me to do some kind of tests on Eclipse just tell. Thanks.

Comment: I've installed Netbeans and QuickFIX/J worked fine with it too.